# Passing int instead of double to planner

Tags: c, fftw

Is it possible use an `int` vector instead of using `double` vectors for fft calculation?

Comment: No, but you can use the single precision (`float`) version of the FFTW libraries (`libfftw3f.lib`) if you're concerned about data size or speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not using FFTW (which you tagged in the question). There are other libraries, but to be useful in practice you will need to give some thought to the fixed point representation of your choice.

Note that floating point additions and multiplications, what's used in an FFT, is just as fast on modern x64 chips as integer operations of corresponding word size. The extra care needed to create an integer FFT result with reasonable precision would maybe even cause a slowdown in practice. The story is very different on chips with slower (or none) floating point hardware.

Of course, conversion from integer to floating point itself is not free in the first place, so sometimes it makes sense to stay in floating point for a longer time than what is critically needed.

Comment: My data originates in `int` format. I've got the `int->double` conversion penalty, but I'm fine with that. Thanks.